# Failed to validate the signature of the actionable message card Power Automate

Tags: outlook, office365, power-automate

Power Automate approval flow has an error **" Failed to validate the signature of the actionable message card"** once click on a button to submit a comment. particular flow is still running. please support.

[image]

I have created another new flow using a similar process and the same error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a known OPEN issue with Microsoft: MF491924. The impact seems global and with their product team currently for a fix.

https://code2care.org/power-automate/error-failed-to-validate-signature-actionable-message-card-power-automate-flow

The approval will work well if you use the Teams App as a workaround until the issue is fixed. Since the approval task itself is impacted, creating a new FLOW will also end up with same error.